# Can't see part of the mesh in object mode

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I'm following the book [Introduction to Character Animation in Blender](http://www.amazon.de/Introducing-Character-Animation-Blender-Mullen/dp/0470102608). I stopped a long time ago and now I'm starting again so I'm confused about many things. I know you unhide with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> but that doesn't work. I've read a few threads I found on Google but I could not find the solution. I'm linking to my file so you can look at it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85i1BKJ9r96dWMzREhoNzZUbjg/view?pref=2&pli=1

EDIT: I also can't see the texture I added to the head material. I thought it was because the path to the image had changed, but no. In an earlier version of the file I can fix it by reloading the image (because the path changed), but not in this one. Last thing, any time I hit render it crashes.

Comment: Hi. Looks like someone edited my post and deleted my link. Are links not allowed or is it because I'm new? Ok, I edited it, I think I had to add some tags to the link.

Comment: His name is "poor". But I think he was just improving the post with some tags and stuff from what I saw. Don't know why the link he removed the link. You should be able to see it now. EDIT: Actually it shows that I deleted it. Weird, no way I did.

Comment: @SRCP Nope, no link removed. **you did it** (I assume accidentally), see revision No.5  http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/45482/revisions, since your issue is caused by the armature modifier I just added the correct tags and the link to the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Turn off Armature modifier's ... "Bind to" > Vertex Group.

Note : It also starts to render with no issue.

[image]

You can read more about Armature Modifier > Bind To > Vertex Group
here https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/armature.html?highlight=armature